# For the guests to applaud

Tags: word-usage, phrase-choice

Can I use "for the guests to applaud" in my sentence to say that the woman  likes to please her guests?

"She enjoys cooking for two hours and for the guests to applaud."

Comment: Not unless you mean for the guests to actually applaud (which would be very unusual). You might say something like this: "She enjoys entertaining her guests," or "She enjoys cooking for her guests." That the guests enjoy her efforts is assumed.

Comment: She enjoys cooking for two hours (every day) and her guests' applause.

Answer (score 2):

You would only say that she likes the guests to applaud if you mean that she gets a thrill out of seeing and hearing them clapping, cheering, etc, because of her cooking. You could say that she enjoys cooking and seeing the pleasure of her guests.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically speaking, the sentence is fine.

But it is awkward, and there are many better ways to say it.  For example:

> She enjoys **cooking** for hours and **hearing** the guests applaud
> after dinner.

You do not want to say that she enjoys cooking for exactly two hours.  That would be a bit strange.

> Feeling elated when the guests applaud her, she does not
> mind to cook for hours.
>
> She feels that cooking for hours is worth it because the guests often
> applaud her cooking.

Comment: Maybe her TV show lasts for 2 hours. That is a possibility.

Comment: Is it wrong to use "during" instead of "for" in my sentence?

Comment: @AntoniaA - yes it's wrong.